# Tense agreement and sentence construction

Tags: sentence-construction, aspect

> So, she ***called*** me yesterday; we talked about a lot of stuff, and then she kind of slipped it out that it wouldn't be all that bad if I asked her out today. I ***found*** myself wondering how it'd go, and decided to give it a shot.

> So, she ***had called*** me yesterday, we talked about a lot of stuff, and then she kind of slipped it out that it wouldn't be all that bad if I asked her out today. I ***had found*** myself wondering how it'd go, and decided to give it a shot.

Are both the above grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: Sidenote: I think the idiom is actually "she let it slip," not "she slipped it."

Comment: i'll make sure to make it easier for the answerers from now on. :)

Comment: Also I think "it'd" sounds a little odd. "It would" seems much more natural to me.

Comment: As for your question, it might spend on context. But straight past tense probably works better most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples:

> ...she **called** me...

is better than

> ..she **had called** me...

**Had called** leaves the reader wondering **after what?** did she call you.

> I **found** myself wondering...

is less ambiguous than

> I **had found** myself wondering...

which could also mean you were wondering **before** the conversation when, in fact, you only wondered **after** the conversation.

**Slipped it out** is incorrect, unless ***something*** was slipped out of ***somewhere***:

> She had a gun and **slipped it out** from under her garter.

whereas the meaning here is *saying something unintentionally* in which case **let it slip** should be used.